# Hashtable with different values for single key

Tags: c#, mono, ios-simulator, hashtable, monodevelop

if i have multiple values for same key then how to add it in  hash table 
for example:

```
                   Hashtable hs = new Hashtable();
                      hs["id"]= "x001.xhtml";
                      hs["media-type"]= "application/xhtm+xml"; 
                      hs["href"]= "text/001.xhtml";

                      hs["id"]= "x002.xhtml";
                      hs["media-type"]= "application/xhtm+xml";
                      hs["href"]= "text/002.xhtml";

                     hs["id"]= "x003.xhtml";
                     hs["media-type"]= "application/xhtm+xml";
                     hs["href"]= "text/003.xhtml";
```

this is taking only last group in hashtable i.e

```
                     hs["id"]= "x003.xhtml";
                     hs["media-type"]= "application/xhtm+xml";
                     hs["href"]= "text/003.xhtml";
```

how to solve this....thanks in advance!!

Comment: Looks like you want a list of objects or a Dictionary to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hashtable is *defined* as having unique keys, and the indexer **replaces** existing values. It sounds like you actually want a list of objects, i.e.

```
var list = new List<YourType> {
    new YourType { Id = "x001.xhtml", MediaType = "...", Href = "..." },
    new YourType { Id = "x002.xhtml", MediaType = "...", Href = "..." },
    new YourType { Id = "x003.xhtml", MediaType = "...", Href = "..." }
};
```

with

```
public class YourType {
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string MediaType {get;set;}
    public string Href {get;set;}
}
```

(or similar)

Comment: It's extremely frustrating to see you come up with a complete answer and gather upvotes while I'm still typing. +1 none the less.

Comment: @skolima I shall endeavour to type slower. Sorry.

Comment: Looking at the kind of data the question shows Dictionary<string,YourType> would probably be best

Comment: @Ian well, maybe - but there is nothing in the question that keys *all* the data by (say) `id`. But if it needed lookup by `id`, then yes a dictionary would work well.

Comment: @SamuelRossille it isn't a problem; whatever helps the OP is good

Answer (score 1):

***Solve your problem***

You're not using the right class for yout model.
What you need is a `List<Hashtable>`

***Improve your code***

Also consider writing a class for what you are storing in the `HashTable`.

The best would be to use a `List<YourMedia>`

Then your code would look like:

```
List<Media> medias = new List<Media>();
media.add(new Media("x001.xhtml", "application/xhtm+xml", "text/001.xhtml")
[...]
```